# How to resolve no-param-reassign error in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, eslint

In a Node/JS function, I'm getting ESLint `no-param-reassign` the code is for update a candidate as follow

```
update(candidate) {
    const { id } = candidate;
    if (!id) {
      throw new UserInputError('id is mandatory');
    }

    return this.tx(tableName)
      .returning(Object.values(columnsByProperties))
      .where('id', id)
      .update(prepareCandidate(candidate))
      .reduce((_, b) => camelcaseKeys(b), null)
      .then(x => {
        if (!x) {
          throw new UserInputError(`Candidate "id" with ${id} is not found`);
        }
        x.preferredContact = x.preferredContactHours;
        return x;
      });
  }
```

The error specifically is here `Assignment to property of function parameter 'x'`

```
.then(x => {
   if (!x) {
     throw new UserInputError(`Candidate "id" with ${id} is not found`);
     }
     x.preferredContact = x.preferredContactHours;
     return x;
});
```

Comment: you should store the result in a new object variable and then manipulate with it

Comment: Normally you don't want to assign to a property of the parameter. It mutates the passed parameter which most user don't expect to happen. In your scenario this is most likely not much of a problem, assuming `prepareCandidate` returns a freshly created object. This would mean you could add a comment to disable the warning for this particular piece of code. I'm not exactly sure what it is for ESLint, but most linters offer such an option. Alternatively you can solve the warning be returning a shallow copy of `x` with the property set. `return {...x, preferredContact: x.preferredContactHours}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace:

```js
x.preferredContact = x.preferredContactHours;
return x;
```

With this:

```js
return { ...x, preferredContact: x.preferredContactHours };
```

This way you return a new object instead of modifying the function's parameter.

Now, elaborating a bit. As the [rule's documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-param-reassign) says:

> Assignment to variables declared as function parameters can be misleading and lead to confusing behavior, as modifying function parameters will also mutate the arguments object.

"Confusing behavior" is to be understood as, for example, odd side effects. I remember wreaking havoc in an app because inside a function, I mutated an array that was passed as a parameter. The array was also mutated in the calling code which was **bad**. That's the kind of thing ESLint helps prevent!